# How to run multiple commands in kubernetes cron job

Tags: bash, command-line, kubernetes

I am trying to run multiple commands in a K8s cron job. However, only the first jobs output is showing in the logs. I have this:

```
          containers:
          - name: myjob
            image: postgres 
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - PGPASSWORD=$(echo $password) psql -h $host -p 5432 -U $username -d $db -c "\copy (select * from blah limit 1) to blah.txt" ; echo bar.txt ; cat bar.txt;
            - PGPASSWORD=$(echo $password) psql -h $host -p 5432 -U $username -d $db -c "\copy (select * from foo limit 1) to foo.txt" ; date ; echo foo.txt ; cat foo.txt;
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I am only seeing the output from the first command. I would like to be able to specify multiple commands and run them one by one.

Answer (score 2):

just join them in a single line after `-c` with `&&` or `;` operator

See the complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33888424/2781331)

Comment: Since the `-c` appears separately from every other line, perhaps an updated example would be helpful?

Comment: The `&&` is only the answer in case your first command is always successful.  If that is not always the case, then the second command might not run at all.

Comment: @Alex in the case you want both no matter what, use `;`

Answer (score 1):

Just can run two commands by a [standard procedure in Pod.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887194/how-to-set-multiple-commands-in-one-yaml-file-with-kubernetes)

```
command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
args: ["command one; command two && command three"]
```

However, **I doubt it is a good idea** and it should be used as last hope. Containers [are designed to run only one process](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container) and CronJobs use [Pod specification](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#writing-a-job-spec).

Hence, I can recommend the following things. Order matters.

- Run two separate CronJobs if your tasks are completely independent.
- Run two separate containers in CronJob. 
  The CronJob will fail, if one of your containers fail.
- [Use `initContainers`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to achieve some order or preparation before.